# Не работает swiper slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper

Пытаюсь использовать swiper slider, но он почему-то помещает все слайды в один вот таким образом[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

не понимаю в чем моя ошибка, делаю все по документации, вот код

```
const slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
```

let mySwiper = new Swiper(slider, {

```
slidesPerView: 1,
spaceBetween: 10,
loop: true,
pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    clickable: true,
},
navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
},
```

})

Comment: приведите пример разметки для слайдера

Comment: Вас просят привести пример разметки. Мой вам совет, попробуйте воспроизвести проблему в мини-примере. Например на https://jsfiddle.net/. 
И если там не заработает, то выложить пример от туда. В примере указываете минимальное количество контента. Я уверен, что как попробуете это сделать вы сами сможете разобраться.

Comment: спасибо за отзывчивость, я разобралась в чем проблема была)